# Как сделать относительный импорт в python?

Tags: python

У меня есть 2 бота на python, проект выглядит примерно так:

```
Bot/
      __init__.py
      main.py
      admin.py
      assets
      client.py
      db.db
Clash/
      __init__.py
      main.py
      admin.py
      qwe
      bot.py
      db.db
```

Мне надо как-то импортировать conn, cursor базы данных первого бота в файл bot.py второго бота. При относительном импорте ошибка: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Относительный импорт будет работать только если оба пакеты будут лежать в общем родительском пакете, и будет запущено снаружи этого пакета как модуль, а не отдельный скрипт (типа `python -m common.Clash.main`)